# Node.js readline with interactive child_process spawning

Tags: node.js, stdin, readline, spawn, child-process

I'm working on simple CLI, one of it's function is to run ssh to remote servers.
This is an example of what I mean:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var readline = require('readline');

var iface =readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});
iface.setPrompt("host> ");

iface.on("line", function(line) {
  if (line.trim() == "") {
    return iface.prompt();
  }
  var host = line.split()[0];
  iface.pause(); // PAUSING STDIN!
  var proc = spawn('ssh', [ host, '-l', 'root', '-o', 'ConnectTimeout=4' ], { stdio: [0,1,2] });
  proc.on("exit", function(code, signal) {
    iface.prompt();
  });
});
iface.prompt();
```

I use iface.pause() to make child process able to read from STDIN exclusively, if I remove this line, some symbols will be catched by remote server, another ones - by local readline.
But this `pause()` really freezes stdin so if ssh waits for connect too long or trying to ask me for password, I can't send any character because stdin is paused. I don't really know how ssh handles (paused?) stdin after successful connect but somehow it works. The question is "How to detach stdin from readline without pausing it while interactive child process is working and to attach it back after child process is finished?"

Answer (score 7):

The problem was solved by adding `setRawMode(false)` right before spawning process. As far as I understand, this makes node release stdin from any transformations it makes to handle keypresses of functional keys. Solved version of code follows:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var readline = require('readline');

var iface =readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});
iface.setPrompt("host> ");

iface.on("line", function(line) {
  if (line.trim() == "") {
    return iface.prompt();
  }
  var host = line.split()[0];
  iface.pause(); // PAUSING STDIN!
  process.stdin.setRawMode(false); // Releasing stdin
  var proc = spawn('ssh', [ host, '-l', 'root', '-o', 'ConnectTimeout=4' ], { stdio: [0,1,2] });
  proc.on("exit", function(code, signal) {
    // Don't forget to switch pseudo terminal on again
    process.stdin.setRawMode(true); 
    iface.prompt();
  });
});
```

Comment: have you tried to write to stdin directly from the `childprocess`? I mean `proce.stdin.on('data', iface.input.write.bind(iface.input))` that might also work.

Comment: Thank you, this was incredibly helpful!

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, one solution to this problem may be to just not use child processes for doing ssh client connections. There is a pure-JavaScript ssh client for node called [`ssh2`](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2). Not only would it be more lightweight than spawning a bunch of child processes, but it may be a lot easier to work with.

Comment: Glad to see you here @mscdex. I've already tried to use your `ssh2` module and it's really great for making parallel execution of tasks on a number of servers at a time. But implementing interactive shell via `ssh2` for me is a real headache. The number of actions I have to do just not to break tab-autocomplete and other raw tty actions, and to handle window resize, and so on, makes me think it's simplier to use native ssh for that.